# I want to mark some sections as “advanced topics” with an asterisk after the label

Tags: titlesec

Titlesec, 4.3. Variants, p.12 gives the following code:

```
    \newcommand{\secmark}{} 
\newenvironment{advanced}
  {\renewcommand{\secmark}{*}}
  {}    
\titleformat{\section}
{..}
{\thesection\secmark\quad}{..}{..}
```

To mark the sections write

```
\begin{advanced}
\section{...}
...
\end{advanced}
```

but I don't know how this fits with the existing titlesec code. Here is a MWE with the three lines in the preamble that seem to prevent compilation commented out:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{book}
    \usepackage{titlesec} 
        \titleformat{\subsection}%formatting subsections
            [runin]%
            {\normalfont\bfseries}%
            {\hspace{10mm}\arabic{subsection}}%format title number
            {10mm}%Space between title number and title text
        {}%???
        {}%???
\newcommand{\secmark}{}
\newenvironment{advanced}
  {\renewcommand{\secmark}{*}}
  {}
%%%==============Begin code I think prevents compilation    
%       \titleformat{\section}
%       {..}
 %      {\thesection\secmark\quad}{..}{..}
%%%==============End code I think prevents compilation  

\begin{document}
\chapter{How to deal with Titlesec}
    \section{Usual Stuff}
That's \emph{relevant} stuff I had forgotten and which I had got by trial and error.
    \subsection{Formatting subsections.} This is the code  which I used according to \textbf{3. Advanced Interface} (p. 3):
    
    \textbackslash titleformat\{\textbackslash subsection\}\hspace{20mm}\% formatting subsection titles
        
            [runin]\hspace{10mm}\%Forces the content to follow immediately upon the title.
            
            \{\textbackslash normalfont\textbackslash bfseries\}%
            
            \{\textbackslash hspace\{10mm\}/arabic\{subsection\}\}\hspace{5mm}\%Formats the title number
            
            \{10mm\}\hspace{55.5mm}\%Space title number / text
            
        \{\}\hspace{30mm}\%???

        \{\}\hspace{30mm}\%???
    
\begin{advanced}
    \section{Advanced Stuff}    
I want to star \emph{this} section according to \textbf{4.3. Variants} (p. 12): "Let’s suppose we want to mark some sections as “advanced topics” with an asterisk after the label. The following code does the job:"

Since I can't make it work, I am commenting the part in the Preamble that prevents compilation.
\end{advanced}  
\end{document}
```

Of which, here is a pdf: [image]

Comment: They are (in this order) the first (general commands for both label and title), third (separation between label and title) and fourth (commands applying to the title) mandatory arguments of \titleformat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this solution, you prefix `\section` with `\advanced` when you want it to be starred.

This prefix sets `\ifadvanced` to true, so when the section number is typeset it will be followed by the asterisk. In any case the conditional is set to false before typesetting the section title.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{titlesec} 

\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}
  {\thesection\advancedmark}
  {1em}
  {\global\advancedfalse}

\newif\ifadvanced
\newcommand{\advancedmark}{\ifadvanced\makebox[0pt][l]{*}\fi}
\newcommand{\advanced}{\global\advancedtrue}

\begin{document}

\chapter{How to deal with Titlesec}

\section{Usual Stuff}

That's \emph{relevant} stuff I had forgotten and which I had got by trial and error.

\advanced\section{Unusual Stuff}

This is mainly for demonstration purposes.

\section{Normal Stuff}

The missing asterisk means this is a normal section.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want that the star appears also in cross-references and the table of contents, you can use an environment around the advanced sections, but this requires a bit of back and forth.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{titlesec,etoolbox}

\newenvironment{advanced}
 {\appto\thesection{\addstar}}
 {}
\newrobustcmd{\addstarintitle}{\makebox[0pt][l]{*}}
\newrobustcmd{\addstar}{*}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\normalfont\bfseries\let\addstar\addstarintitle}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begingroup
\let\addstar\addstarintitle
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\mainmatter

\chapter{How to deal with Titlesec}

\section{Usual Stuff}

That's \emph{relevant} stuff I had forgotten and which I had got by trial and error.

\begin{advanced}
\section{Unusual Stuff}\label{unusual}

This is mainly for demonstration purposes. The reference~\ref{unusual} is correct.
\end{advanced}

\section{Normal Stuff}

The missing asterisk means this is a normal section.

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Works beautifully. Coming from egreg, what else. But I should have said that I would like the star to show in the TOC entry and also in the chaptertoc entry. How should I provide the modified MWE?

Comment: @schremmer I added a possible solution.

Comment: Works fine of course. Tried to adapt it to \ChapterToc from:  \usepackage{afterpage} \newcommand{\ChapterToc}{\startcontents[chapters]\printcontents[chapters]{p-}{1}{}\vspace{10mm}} \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}. I know, I know, but that's all I could come up with to compile chapters on their own as well as in the whole book. (I couldn't stand \includeonly.)

Comment: @schremmer Please consider accepting the answer as ist seems that is solved your problem.